# Hive create table with SERDEPROPERTIES throwing error

Tags: hive, hdfs, hiveql

Below part of my Hive create table query is failing:

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED                                                               
   NULL DEFINED AS ''
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (                                                             
   'escapeChar'='\\',                                                               
   'quoteChar'='\'',                                                                
   'separatorChar'='^')
```

and getting error as "Error: Error while compiling statement:

> FAILED: ParseException line 59:0 missing EOF at 'WITH' near ''''
>   (state=42000,code=40000)"

Can anyone help me out.

Thanks for Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with **`'serialization.null.format'`** in TBLPROPERTIES instead of specifying `NULL DEFINED AS ''`, then hive will treat `empty spaces` as `NULL`.

**`Example:`**

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
TBLPROPERTIES (                                                             
   'escapeChar'='\\',                                                               
   'quoteChar'='\'',                                                                
   'separatorChar'='^',
   'serialization.null.format'='');
```